# How can I prevent a sticky footer + content editable div from having overlapping content

Tags: html, css, contenteditable, sticky-footer

So I have a jsfiddle describing a contenteditable div with a sticky footer area representing: https://jsfiddle.net/xd5p1h7u/

CSS

```
.textarea {
  background: white;
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
.footer {
  height: 20px;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  background: blue;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="textarea" contenteditable="true"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

If you type until you get to the bottom of the screen, you'll notice that the sticky footer covers up the bottom content. I've tried a variety of the typical techniques like adding bottom/top margins and paddings in various places to prevent the content from getting covered up.

Is there a purely css way to achieve this effect without overlapping content?

Comment: Posted an answer though a question that came up was, do you want the sticky footer to stay as it does in the sample I gave or should it being pushed down along with the `textarea`? ... Also, the behavior you see in your question is the expected behavior when using `position: sticky`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By update your CSS like this, does that solve your issue?

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xd5p1h7u/1/)

Stack snippet

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
.textarea {
  background: white;
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 20px);
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.footer {
  height: 20px;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="textarea" contenteditable="true">
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
</div>
<div class="footer">

</div>
```